# Spring cassandra Batch Operation delete by partition key only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

I have a requirement in which i have to perform a delete operation in cassandra by using only partiton key (delete all records with the partition key ) under batch operation using spring and springboot ,but the CassandraBatchOperations 's delete method only takes in input full entity object like

```
CassandraBatchOperations delete(Object... entities);
```

i have a table say table1
and it has keys :
key1- partiton key ,
key2 -clustering key1 ,
key 3-clustering key2

```
so my requirement is that in batch operation below query should run
DELETE from table1 where key1='input key';


so when i create an object like 
tableEntity recordToDelete=new Table1Entity();
recordToDelete.setKey1('input key');

and run batchOperations like 
CassandraBatchOperations batchOps=cassandraTemplate.batchOps();
batchOps.delete(recordToDelete);

then the effective query getting generated is 
DELETE from table1 where key1='input key' and key2=null and key3=null
```

then i am getting below exception

```
>  rg.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: 
> Query; CQL [BEGIN BATCH DELETE FROM table1 WHERE key2=null AND
> key3=null AND key1='0002';APPLY BATCH;]; Invalid null value in
> condition for column key2; nested exception is
> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid
> null value in condition for column key2
```

The problem is the query getting create is also considering the clustering key key2 and key3 which does not have values as i want to delete only by partition key .

I want to know how can i delete only by partiton Key ,
Getting the list of record from DB is not an option as i am also inserting the records in cassandra under same batch operation and it can happen that there is also a record getting instered in the same batch operation which has the partition key that i want to delete . so in that case if i get and delete the record the new record that is getting inserted in batch operation will not get deleted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to this question was my Entity class was containing all  the pk ( as it should)
so when the Cassandra Template created the query it was picking up all the keys

**Original Entity class**

```
@Table(CassandraDBSchemaConstants.TABLE1)
public class Table {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn (name = CassandraDBSchemaConstants.KEY1 , type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String key1;
    
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = CassandraDBSchemaConstants.KEY2 , type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String key2;
    
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = CassandraDBSchemaConstants.KEY3 , type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String key3;
    
    
    ..//other columns
    
    }
```

so as fix : I created a new Entity class with same table name with only 1 key (partition key ) in it

**a new class apart from the existing entity class**

```
@Table(CassandraDBSchemaConstants.TABLE1)
public class TableOnlyByPartitonKey {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn (name = CassandraDBSchemaConstants.KEY1 , type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String key1;
    
    }
```

and when I had to delete by partition key only I passed the new entity class to the cassandra batch operation's delete method

and the query that got executed deleted the record only by the partition key which was present in new entity class

Comment: Glad you figured it out!